# Blank screen above keyboard in adjustResize mode

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

when open on screen keyboard blank screen show above keyboard when called with text field ,
in Manifest
windowSoftInputMode : adjustResize

Used versions:
jetpack compose v1.5.4
Material 3 v1.2.1
android 9 or 10

[image]

I didn't find any solution